# Android. BroadcastReceiver завершает работу при выходе из приложения

Tags: android, kotlin, service, broadcast-receiver

Использую BroadcastReceiver для отклонения входящих звонков. BroadcastReceiver прекращает работу, когда пользователь выходит из приложения или очищает ОЗУ. Как сделать так, чтобы BroadcastReceiver работал постоянно? Я хотел использовать Service, но тогда возникает проблема в реализации сброса звонков.

```
class PhoneCallStateReceiver : BroadcastReceiver() {
private lateinit var mTelephonyManager: TelephonyManager

override fun onReceive(context: Context?, intent: Intent?) {

    //сброс звонка

    mTelephonyManager = context!!.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE) as TelephonyManager
    val c = Class.forName(mTelephonyManager.javaClass.name)
    val m = c.getDeclaredMethod("getITelephony")
    m.isAccessible = true
    val telephonyService = m.invoke(mTelephonyManager) as ITelephony
    val bundle = intent!!.extras
    val phoneNumber = bundle!!.getString("incoming_number")
    phoneNumber.toString().replace("[^0-9]", "")
    Log.e("INCOMING", phoneNumber.toString())
    if ((phoneNumber != null)) {
        telephonyService.endCall()
        Log.d("HANG UP", phoneNumber)
    }

}
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Android не разрешает выполнять какие-либо операции в фоне без ведома пользователя. Соответственно, если вы хотите, чтобы ваше приложение что-то делало даже после того, как пользователь выгрузит приложение из памяти, вам необходимо создать [Foreground Service](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/foreground-services?hl=ru).

Если вы посмотрите, то именно так сейчас работают все фоновые приложения, такие как: Музыкальные плееры, Google переводчик, Навигаторы и многое другое.

Другого способа у вас скорее всего нет, потому как любые другие действия будет убивать система. В теории вы конечно можете запустить какой-нибудь WorkManager, который будет стартовать ваше приложение раз в какое-то время. Но я не уверен, что это будет работать стабильно.

Например, я знаю ребят которые так запускают некое невидимое активити для того, чтобы их приложение работало в фоне. Но ребята пишут много нативного SDK и работают с IoT (Internet of Things). Так что, я не знаю насколько стоит такое делать и насколько это сложно.